# Restrict deletion on UITextField

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield, restriction

I've a `UITextField` with text like, `+91-` (that's country caller code of India). Now when my user input his number into that textfield, it would look like this, `+91-1234567890` that's good, now when he tap (x) delete key from keyboard, I want to restrict deletion, its only possible up to, `1` (first digit of his mobile number), at any case, he should not be able to delete `+91-`. I'm able to do it  with `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;` delegate, like this,

1) First way:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([string isEqualToString:@""]) { //detect back space
        if([textField.text hasSuffix:@"-"]) { //has suffix `-`
            return NO;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Second way:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //if text length is length of caller code and detect back space
    if(textField.text.length<=4 && [string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

In both the ways, I'm getting what I want, but not sure its proper or not? Any more smoother way?

Answer (score 1):

why you not try just like the simple method add the one more `UIView` in prefix of the `UItextfield`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply show a non-editable `UILabel` before the `UITextField` where the user actually enters the number. When you get the input from the user and want to process it, prefix "+91-" before the user input string